# Migration to replace `async` pipe with `ngrxPush`

Tags: angular, ngrxpush

While using the Angular schematics to generate my angular code I noticed the line

> ngrx-push-migration - Migration to replace `async` pipe with `ngrxPush`

This looked interesting so I googled and found

> The `ngrxPush` pipe serves as a drop-in replacement for the async pipe. It contains intelligent handling of change detection to enable us running in zone-full as well as zone-less mode without any change to the code

This sounds interesting so I decided to give it a shot but it seems to require options

[image]

Any advice? And is it safe to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

As written in `https://ngrx.io/guide/component/push`, this migration is safe ин pipe change.